# Do villagers lose food every time they enter breeding mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Do they lose food every time they enter breeding mode? Or do they only lose food the first time they notice they are willing to breed (correct conditions but not in breeding mode yet)

Comment: What verson? The latest one?

Comment: @KingsleyZhong yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Breeding)

> Villagers will consume the required food upon becoming willing.

This means that when a Villager becomes "willing" to breed, they will consume the food required to breed, not upon breeding.

Comment: So every time the love hearts pop up?

Comment: Yes, I believe so

Comment: that villager must have been really full of food. He wasn’t emptying to I just had to cure a zombie villager. Thanks for your help.